# Locked convex polyhedra

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry

Call a set of polyhedra *free* if it is possible to rigidly move the polyhedra, without any polyhedron intersecting any other, so that their pairwise distances are arbitrary large, and *locked* otherwise. So two linked tori are locked, as is a ship in a bottle.

Can a finite set of *convex* polyhedra in $\mathbb{R}^3$ ever be locked?

note: We can move these polyhedra simultaneously.

Comment: [This is on M.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1604301/locked-convex-polyhedra) as well. There are useful answers over on that page too.

Comment: Yes, I asked it on M.SE too.

Answer (score 13):

No locking, even if you restrict to translations. Scale the whole arrangement up by a factor of $c$, then scale each polyhedron down by $c$ around its center of mass. Neither step introduces collisions. Now, that's not quite rigid motion like you asked for, so instead do this recipe $N$ times with the factor $\sqrt[N]{c}$, and let $N\to \infty$.

Comment: I do think that one can make a non-moveable arrangement if one restricts the moves to only one polytope at a time.

Comment: @LevBorisov, Do you have a proof? (By some reason I feel there are such examples.)

Comment: @AntonPetrunin I am not sure what are precise statements, but there is something on the topic here and in references http://www.turgor.ru/lktg/2002/problem4.ru/

Answer (score 3):

I have already up-voted Allen's answer (see above). His solution is discrete though. I thought I would write a comment but it's simpler to provide an extension of his method right here. I will even generalize his approach slightly. You may up-vote Allen for all this, instead of my answer.

Let's fix a selection function--given an arbitrary convex body $B\subseteq\mathbb R^n$, let $s(B)\in B$.

Let $F$ be a family of pairwise disjoint convex bodies in $\mathbb R^n\,$ (*bodies* $\,$means$\,$ *compact and n-dimensional*). $\,$Define

$$\forall_{t\ge 1}\ T_t(B)\ := \{x\in\mathbb R^n\,:\, x-(t+1)\cdot s(B)\in B\}$$

Then $T_t\ $ (for $t\ge 1)\ $ move convex bodies $B\in F$ rigidly, and keep them separated all the time, where the separation goes to $\infty$ when $t\rightarrow \infty$.

---

In particular, one can select $s(B)$ to be the center of gravity of $B$.

---

**REMARK** $\,$ We may decide on $s(B)$ being the center of gravity of $B$, as Allen has done. Then $\ \forall_{t\ u\ge 1}\ T_{t\cdot u} = T_u\circ T_t$.

Answer (score 2):

I also asked this question in [M.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1604301/locked-convex-polyhedra/1605903#1605903) and at there Igor Pak gives a quite useful reference book which solve this problem completely.

Comment: He said it is exercise 42.47 in Lectures on Discrete and Polyhedral Geometry available at this URL: http://www.math.ucla.edu/~pak/book.htm

Answer (score 1):

To supplement your references, this class of problems has been studied
since the 1980's:

> Toussaint, Godfried. "Movable separability of sets." *Computational Geometry*. 1985.

---

[image]

---

Google Scholar finds this paper has by now been cited 141 times.

Answer (score 0):

you can use tetrahedrons to cover a sphere in such a way that the two high points of each tetrahedron cover low points of other tetrahedrons, as if they were in a square lattice. not sure what to do where the lattice breaks though. this kind of stracture should stop them from moving one at a time (allen already solved the case otherwise).